# Select points on line by coordinates ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I would like to use ModelBuilder to select points along a polyline between two sets of coordinates then export it as a shapefile (the exporting I can do). Each points represents 1 ft and the line represents a stream. This would be used to calculate sinuous length of stream no flows or areas of interest. So pretty much the number of points between X1,Y1 and X2, Y2 would be the length of the no flow or AOI.

Comment: I'm not sure how to achieve this with Model Builder, but I see Python as a tag - are you open to a Python solution? Also, which ArcGIS version are you running?

Comment: absolutely! I am open to anything at this point, as I am not certain this can be done with model builder. The important thing is that the distance is not a straight line from the coordinates, but sinuous (follows the stream between the two pts).

Comment: Do these points exist already or do you want to calculate them? How are you going to deal with tributary junctions or multi-threaded networks? What if you have pseudo nodes in your network? Although not quite what you are asking RivEX can generate regularly spaced points along a river network, have a look at the help page [here](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Generateregularlyspacedpoints.html) to understand the limitations.

Comment: I have already created the points along the stream polylines using ET Geowizard. It took into consideration the start & end point of the stream polyline layer. So each point on the stream is correctly stationed and represents 1 foot. The X1,Y1 & X2,Y2 points will be calculated prior to running this model or code. I basically want to select all of the points between X1,Y1(downstream pt) and X2, Y2(upstream pt) in a sinuous manner. My guess is that it will try to calculate it in a straight line which does not work for me. The number of points between the two coordinates will be my total length.

Comment: It's not clear what your input datasets are. You say you have a stream layer. Is this a topologically correct network or have you pre-processed it to create "long routes with no junctions"  and generated your 1 foot spaced points? Do you have points u/s and d/s of your X1,Y1,X2,Y2 points? Edit your question and put some images of your data as until we understand what it is you actually have it is difficult to suggest a solution. Also are your polylines (or routes) labelled with ID's that make them unique?

Answer (score 2):

As @Hornbydd points out, there are many stumbling blocks for something like this, but a simple example of one line vs. two points might look like the following. The script outputs the line geometry between points along the stream (which you could use to select your points), and straight/sinuous distances.

```py
points_fc = 'stream_points' # start/end points layer - could also use coordinates
points_sr = arcpy.Describe(points_fc).spatialReference # points spatial ref
point_geoms = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points_fc, 'SHAPE@', spatial_reference=points_sr)] # point geometries
start_pt = point_geoms[0] # first point
end_pt = point_geoms[1] # second point
stream_fc = 'stream' # stream layer
stream_sr = arcpy.Describe(stream_fc).spatialReference # stream spatial ref
stream_geom = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(stream_fc, 'SHAPE@', spatial_reference=stream_sr)][0].projectAs(points_sr) # stream geometry, projected as points spatial ref
start_query_point = stream_geom.queryPointAndDistance(start_pt) # closest point on stream line
end_query_point = stream_geom.queryPointAndDistance(end_pt) # closest point on stream line
start_point_on_stream = start_query_point[0] # point geom from query
end_point_on_stream = end_query_point[0] # point geom from query
start_measure = start_query_point[1] # measure from query
end_measure = end_query_point[1] # measure from query
stream_distance = abs(start_measure-end_measure) # distance along stream
straight_distance = start_point_on_stream.distanceTo(end_point_on_stream) # straight line distance
segment_between_points = stream_geom.segmentAlongLine(start_measure,end_measure) # line segment between points
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management([segment_between_points],r'in_memory\segment_between_points') # write line to disk
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management([start_point_on_stream,end_point_on_stream],r'in_memory\points_on_stream') # write points to disk
print (stream_distance, straight_distance) # do something with distance(s)

(2178.874834228248, 1681.5302040585652)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your idea seems to make more sense bc I won't have to select the points every 1ft. One question I have due to the output of the script is that does it matter the x1,y1 and x2,y2 are in the same row, but each a different column? There are multiple rows, too, in some cases - so multiple x1,y1 and x2,y2

Comment: Here is the image of the my data. The red points are x1,y1 and the green points are x2,y2. After I run a model, they are combined into the red point's attribute table, so I was going to make that my stream points layer.

http://imgur.com/L8xm8zc